# Dynamically Change AngularJS App Document Title on User Search Event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I am implementing a Search feature in my AngularJS tutorial application. So, whenever a user types in the Search `<input>` field, I want to change my document's `<title>`.

For this, I am using `query` model with `ng-bind-template` in my document's `<title>` to avoid double curly braces `{{}}` flicker effect when application loads.

Following is my code for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="icon" href="/assets/img/fav.png">
  <title ng-bind-template="Phonecat | {{query}}">Phonecat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css">
  <script src="/assets/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Search: </span><input ng-model="query" />
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Total number of phones: {{phones.length}}</p>
  <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, my `<title>` tag has `ng-bind-template` directive with `query` model & pre-defined content,

> **Phonecat**

Now, when page loads document `<title>` is set to,

> **Phonecat |**

Instead of just "**Phonecat**".

I don't want `ng-bind-template` to evaluate & change my document's `<title>` if `query` model is **EMPTY**. If `query` model is **EMPTY**, it should just display the initial content (**Phonecat** in this case) as document's Title & when the `query` model is updated & **NOT EMPTY**, it should update the Title (i.e. **Phonecat | nexus mobile**).

It will be great if someone can explain how to approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator inside `ng-binding` to conditionally build the title:

```
<title ng-bind="query ? 'Phonecat | ' + query : 'Phonecat'">Phonecat</title>
```

Alternatively:

```
<title>{{ query ? 'Phonecat | ' + query : 'Phonecat'}}</title>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. If anyone wants to do with `ng-bind-template`, can do `<title ng-bind-template="{{query ? 'Phonecat | ' + query : 'Phonecat'}}"></title>`. Since, I don't want to **bind multiple** values, `ng-bind` is good for me.

Comment: I'll prefer `ng-bind` over the alternate solution, `<title>{{query ? 'Phonecat | ' + query : 'Phonecat'}}</title>`, to avoid the curly brace flicker effect. Thanks!